# Use JavaScript String replace function to remove a function in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this string

```
str = 'function1(function2(function3(param1,param2,param3),paramfunction2))'
```

And I would like to remove the function3 and replace it by the param1. I could I have more functions around function3 but i know the name of this function and it doesn't change.

The expected result is

```
function1(function2(param1,paramfunction2))
```

In JavaScript I do

```
str.replace(/function3[(](.*),.*,.*[)]/,'$1')
```

And I always get, I can't isolate just the function3

```
function1(function2(param1,param2
```

Comment: `'function1(function2(function3(param1,param2,param3),paramfunction2))'.replace(/function3\([^)]*\)/, 'param1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't JavaScript-specific. You should use non-greedy quantifiers instead of the greedy ones.

```
str.replace(/function3[(](.*?),.*?,.*?[)]/,'$1')
```

Note the question marks.

Comment: it's working thanks. How did you know that the last bracket is the  bracket of the function3 ?

Comment: Learn the difference between greedy and non-greedy quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you are looking for: (function3\([^\)]*\))